# I belive I deleted the template

Tags: pages, block-editor, page-template, editor

I'm new to wordpress and I don't even know what exactly is wrong with my WP so bear with me for a bit.

The steps I performed:

- Picked a blank canvas theme and from the several headers and footers options I chose one of each
- I started by editing my site trough the edit button on the bottom right corner when you are viewing the site
- Then editing the home page
- Then creating a new one and editing it [image: through this menu]
- when I was editing on the URL like menu text box on top (one with ctrl+K) it said "page"

Later on I went through [image: Worpress admin center > pages > all pages > "nature photos"] and I had a different layout from the one I had configured earlier so I redid the layout I wanted thinking I didn't save the one before just to realise that they appear to be 2 distinct things.

So Now I am very confused.

1. What are each of the editing modes called?
2. Which one should I be editing?
3. When I edit through `Worpress admin center > pages > all pages > "nature photos"` no changes appear on the site. How can I make it so that they appear?